# Connecting a geophone to Arduino

Tags: arduino, filter, microphone

Simple question: I want to connect my geophone to an Arduino input. The geophone I have is actually output to a microphone jack and I can plug it directly into my computer. I'm pretty sure I can treat it like a microphone, but not positive.

The purpose of this project is to detect footsteps, which I have determined to be in the 7-30 Hz range on my bedroom floor. (While I'm here, anyone know of any easy, low-frequency low-pass and possibly high pass filter to write in the software?)

Comment: What are the output voltages of your geophone? I suppose you can connect it to your arduino's ADC through a non-inverting amplifier.

Comment: I'm not sure. It's basically an accelerometer, so I'm not sure if there's a hard limit to the output voltage. I think it's okay to treat it like a microphone, though, because it's not like I'm going to subject it to any extreme acceleration, and I don't need to read very high values.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the schematic [here](http://www.infiltec.com/seismo/). It implements a rail-to-rail amplifier and a lowpass filter.

Comment: @AshtonHearts: Thanks. I think I've determined I'll make the low pass filter in software, because really I only need to monitor a few hundred hertz. How should I select which kind of amplifier to use? I'm at a loss with all the options. Something simple would probably work for my purposes--I'm not terribly concerned with maintaining the fidelity of the signal. Also: what are the drawbacks to just using a non-inverting amplifier, and how do I determine what resistor values to use? Thanks!

Comment: I would go for a low noise op-amp. [LT1677](http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee133/datasheets/LT1677.pdf) is a low-noise precision rail-to-rail op-amp. Other amps like [LF353](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf353-n.pdf) or [LM358](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) from TI would also fit your needs. To determine the resistor values you can use this [calculator](http://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Op-Amp/NonInverting-Op-Amp-Resistor-Calculator.phtml) and specify desired gain. To determine the gain level you have to know the output voltages of your sensor. [continue..]

Comment: [..continue]. Connect your geophone to a scope and determine minimum and maximum output voltages. The next step is to 'scale' these levels so that they were as close as possible to your ADC's input range (0..5V). I would also use a lower reference voltage for ADC (2.56V) to get higher precision.

Comment: @AshtonHearts, unfortunately I am scopeless but I just realized for my purposes something like this will do: http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Prac/winscope.htm. Also, setting the reference voltage on my Arduino to 2.56 V means that it would simply read between 0 and 2.56 volts, correct? Why exactly does that help? Would it result in less noise? (Not challenging your claim, but simply curious.)

Comment: Setting a lower reference voltage will result in higher precision. For example, if Vref = 5V and ADC resolution is 10 bits than the sensitivity of your ADC will be `5V/1024` which is about 5mV. That means your ADC will not sense any signal with amplitude less than 5mV. When Vref = 2.56V you get `2.56V/1024 = 2.5mV`. You can go even lower than 2.56V for Vref if you want to, however this will require a very stable power source. Since ATmega microcontrollers provide internal 2.56V reference voltage generator this is the easiest option.

Comment: @AshtonHearts, I'll be using the Arduino Uno as I already have it. It doesn't have a 2.56 internal reference voltage, but I can build a voltage divider and feed that into AREF (http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogReference?from=Reference.AREF). But are you sure that's necessary? couldn't I simply scale up my signal so it fluctuates between 0-5V instead of between 0-2.56 V? It seems the precision would be the same either way.

Comment: I never worked with arduino but according to the datasheet of ATmega328 (which is used in Uno) it offers 1.1V ADC reference voltage. I suppose you can enable it in your arduino by using `analogReference(INTERNAL)`. It is not necessary, but I would definitely recommend doing so. If you really want to know the influence of reference voltage on ADC than you can read this [article](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt331/slyt331.pdf) by Texas Instruments.